# How is waiting for I/O or waiting for a lock to be released implemented?

Tags: python, multithreading, io

I'm curious. I've been programming in Python for years. When I run a command that blocks on I/O (whether it's a hard-disk read or a network request), or blocks while waiting on a lock to be released, how is that implemented? How does the thread know when to reacquire the GIL and start running again?

I wonder whether this is implemented by constantly checking ("Is the output here now? Is it here now? What about now?") which I imagine is wasteful, or alternatively in a more elegant way.

Comment: I'm not Python developer so take this comment with a grain of salt. I/O execution is performed by operating system, and language runtime just wraps around that. Windows for example always provides synchronous I/O operations, but runtimes provide methods which run I/O on separate threads. Those threads themselves are informed of data using interrupts. Similar thing should be with locks. Check to perform if lock is released, and if not CPU is yielded back to OS scheduler which runs different thread for a period of time, and returns control to lock checking code periodically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to repeatedly check for either I/O completion or for lock release.

An I/O completion, signaled by a hardware interrupt to a driver, or a lock release as signaled by a software interrupt from another thread, will make threads waiting on those operations ready 'immediately', and quite possibly running, and quite possibly preempting another thread when being made running.  Essentially, after either a software or hardware interrupt, the OS can decide to interrupt-return to a different thread than the one interrupted.

The high I/O performance of this mechanism, eliminating any polling or checking, is 99% of the reason for putting up with the pain of premptive multitaskers.